# How to redirect to the latest post/article correctly without impacting SEO?

Tags: seo, 302-redirect, negative-seo

I'm working on a site that will showcase the latest photos from photographers and there'll be minimum text e.g. description of the photo, location of the photo, etc.

The site will deployed using WordPress. One of the requirements is that the latest photo be shown on the home page (and the content will be updated daily and as a result there will always be a latest post with different titles). The second requirement is that the photo(s) is/are displayed on in a single post i.e. not a page.

The third requirement is that the navigation pagination is the title of the post and not numbers e.g. Previous (the URL would be `https://www.example.com/mountain-cliff`) | Next (URL would be `https://www.example.com/rapid-waters`) rather than `https://www.example.com/page/2/`.

Currently, if a user visits the home page, he/she/they is/are redirected (302) to the latest post e.g. `https://www.example.com/mountain-cliff` as there doesn't appear to be a way to achieve the same outcome natively or using hooks in WordPress.

Assuming there isn't (and even if there is, the site needs to be launched tomorrow so it'll need to explored long after it has gone live), what is the correct way to redirect without impacting SEO in the short and long term (assuming it has to function in the way it is now i.e. redirect to the latest post?

Comment: Why redirect?   WordPress by default features the latest posts on the home page.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - It displays these as part of a blog roll or index. If the `Blog pages show at most` is set to 1, the pagination navigation reads as `https://www.example.com/page/2/` rather than `https://www.example.com/mountain-cliff`. The URI varies depending on whether WordPress is configured to display the entire post or an excerpt. If the latter, it requires the user to "read more" for the URL to be display as `https://www.example.com/mountain-cliff`.

Comment: You wouldn't normally show just one item on the home page with WordPress. Have you disabled WordPress pagination? [How to disable content pagination?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208760/how-to-disable-content-pagination)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - The home page is intended to show the latest collection of photos for a given post. If a user wants to have a look at older posts, they can navigate to "Older" (which when hovered over would show the URL e.g. `https://www.example.com/rapid-waters`. When they are on the `https://www.example.com/rapid-waters` post, they can either navigate to an older post or the newest at that time e.g. `https://www.example.com/mountain-cliff`.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - This is the intended outcome for a navigation/pagination perspective. The guidance/help I'm after is the redirection when someone hits the home page.

Comment: Redirecting the home page is not usually a good idea either for users or SEO. I think I get what you are going for, but I wouldn't recommend that route.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - What would your recommendation be? What are the alternatives to achieve the same outcome?